# Excel Formula for Counting 1st and 2nd Occurrence

Tags: excel-formula

Out of 4 weeks, I can visit or not visit a store, and on each visit I can or cannot conduct an activity.

How can I use a formula to count whether an activity was conducted on my first and second visits?- There could be as many as 4 visits or as few as zero visits, but I only want to look at the first and second visit, and if there was an activity performed during those specific visists.

My example data is arranged in 9 Columns; Row 1 is the store number, Row 2 tells me if a i visited the store in week 1 and Row 3 tells me if I conducted an activity on my visit in Week 1, repeats for each week and all data is 1s and 0s. The result i need is three rows; representing each possible visit and the count of activities in that visit by store number.

I can use multiple IF statements to determine what happened in the first visit, but I am stuck on the second visit.

[IMG]https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqOQJ.png - I have updated the image - Should have been activities per visit and I have also changed the word Call to Visit.

Comment: add an external link to the image plz from imgur for example

Comment: Please define the concept of a 'call,' introduced in third paragraph without context.

Comment: Also you seem to use Week 1 & Week 2 with two different definitions in the spreadsheet.  In the lower section do you mean Call 1 & Call 2 (e.g. first and second visit to a store?)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a sum product. Move the columns so all the Visits are adjacent to each other and all the Activities are adjacent to each other so you can click and drag them as arrays.

Then do a sumproduct to multiply the Visit array by the Activity array. If the sumproduct for a row = 2, then the user performed the activity in both the weeks he visited.

**=SUMPRODUCT(B2:E2,F2:I2)**

Screenshot with formula and example table below

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8guruiv8ct2eheu/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-02%20at%201.22.40%20PM.png?dl=0